# Is $|x+y|_p=\mathrm{max}(|x|_p,|y|_p)$ for $p$-adic norm? Sanity test.

Tags: solution-verification, p-adic-number-theory, nonarchimedian-analysis

I apologize in advance, if this is a stupid question. I thought about this for some time and don't see any mistake in my reasoning, even after carefully typing up the proof here. I think this is true

**Claim.** For any non-zero $x,y\in\mathbb{Q}$ we have that
$$
|x+y|_p\color{red}{=}\mathrm{max}(|x|_p,|y|_p).
$$

**Proof.**

Let $x=\frac{a}{b}p^n$, $y=\frac{c}{d}p^m$, where $a,b,c,d,n,m\in\mathbb{Z}$; $a,b,c,d\neq 0$ and $a,b,c,d$ are not divisible by $p$; $\mathrm{gcd} (a,b)=1$, $\mathrm{gcd} (c,d)=1$.

We have $|x|_p=\frac{1}{p^n}$, $|x|_p=\frac{1}{p^m}$.

Let $n>m$. Then

$$\mathrm{max}(|x|_p,|y|_p)=\frac{1}{p^m}.\tag{1}$$

We have
$$
|x+y|_p=\Big|\frac{a}{b}p^n+\frac{c}{d}p^m\Big|_p=|p^m|_p\cdot \Big|\frac{a}{b}p^{n-m}+\frac{c}{d}\Big|_p\\
=\frac{1}{p^m}\cdot \Big|\frac{adp^{n-m}+bc}{bd}\Big|_p.
$$
Since $n-m>0$ and the nonzero integers $ad$, $bc$ are not divisible by $p$, we have that the integer $adp^{n-m}+bc$ is nonzero and is not divisible by $p$. Since the non zero integer $bd$ is not divisible by $p$ either, we have
$$
\Big|\frac{adp^{n-m}+bc}{bd}\Big|_p=1.
$$
Thus using $(1)$
$$
|x+y|_p=\mathrm{max}(|x|_p,|y|_p)\cdot 1=\mathrm{max}(|x|_p,|y|_p)
$$
as claimed. $\Box$

In the book I'm reading it is proved that
$$
|x+y|_p \color{red}{\leq} \mathrm{max}(|x|_p,|y|_p).
$$

I feel like I'm loosing my sanity. Please, help me.

Comment: It is equal when $|x|\ne |y|$, otherwise it may be $<$.

Comment: The most striking example to always have in mind for $\lvert x+y\rvert < \max(\lvert x\rvert, \lvert y\rvert)$ is $y=-x$ (and $x \neq 0$ arbitrary).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your proof is fine for the case when $n > m$ and by symmetry also proves the result when $n < m$. However when $n = m$ we have

$$x + y  = {p^m}\cdot\frac{ad+bc}{bd}$$

and $ad + bc$ could be divisible by $p$.

Comment: Wow, I'm so stupid. Thanks.